# Did the Chinese government kill Falun Gong practitioners for their organs?

Tags: china

Did the Chinese government kill Falun Gong practitioners for their organs?

https://www.healtheuropa.eu/forced-organ-harvesting-they-kill-innocent-people-for-their-organs/97306/

Articles such as these claim that the Chinese government is doing so, but I rarely see enough evidences for these outlandish claims. What are some proofs of this from independent sources?

> The doctor knew. He was responsible for cornea transplants, and he
>   knew that the people whose corneas he was using were alive. And he
>   also knew they were just there [so the hospital could] take their
>   cornea and conduct transplants to make money.

Comment: It doesn't mention if they are killed specifically for the harvesting, and where the death figures for the practitioners come from.

Comment: It looks like a direct duplicate to me. It explains that they are imprisoned for their belief system and then killed to meet organ needs. I don't understand what "death figures" means in this claim.